# Can a Heroku app access remote database?

Tags: heroku

I want to host an application in Heroku bu don't want to use a Heroku database.  Can I connect to an existing remote database from my Heroku app?

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever database you like from Heroku as long as it is accessible from Heroku's platform.

Just set and use the proper env var in your app with your db's address and credentials and it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your current database hosted? In short, the answer is likely yes. Heroku makes it really easy to connect to an Amazon RDS instance through a plugin. This is the same way many other database hosts provide connectivity, such as ClearDB or MongoLab. If you share where your current remote database is, it will be easier to give you more information.

Comment: The remote database is a SQLServer database that is not hosted in a cloud, but rather on a private server.

Comment: Okay, then you're solution likely will not involve a heroku add-on, however as GregB stated, you should be fine to connect as just as you would using your db's address and proper credentials. 

Note that heroku's add-ons dont do anything special at all for connecting. All they do is set the environment variables for you ( and create an instance if you asked it to). Connecting is still the same.